# JavaServer Faces and Tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat

Can I run JavaServer Faces technology on tomcat server, or I need to use application server, like glassfish, jboss etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I run JavaServer Faces technology on tomcat server

Yes.

> or I need to use application server, like glassfish, jboss etc?

No.